# Closing token accounts with spl-token close not working

Tags: spl-token, close

I'm trying to close token accounts with `spl-token close <address>`. But I'm not able to close any account with 0 tokens. The error is it cannot parse the token account, and points back to my owner pubkey.

Hereby relevant console output:

```
$ spl-token close 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5
Error: Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey=TestqXotSYZhoAoFGpGxjzwXhrKh5pdgiZzU48vFeoW
```

```
$ spl-token close --address 83kaPUwngQs9ffJ4RHWPc3xXR6oPpmnT4fAmQWWdyp9a
Error: Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey=TestqXotSYZhoAoFGpGxjzwXhrKh5pdgiZzU48vFeoW
```

```
$ spl-token close --address 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5
Error: Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey=2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5
```

```
$ spl-token accounts -v
Token                                         Account                                       Balance
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5  83kaPUwngQs9ffJ4RHWPc3xXR6oPpmnT4fAmQWWdyp9a  0
```

```
$ spl-token account-info 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5

Address: 83kaPUwngQs9ffJ4RHWPc3xXR6oPpmnT4fAmQWWdyp9a
Balance: 0
Mint: 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5
Owner: TestqXotSYZhoAoFGpGxjzwXhrKh5pdgiZzU48vFeoW
State: Initialized
Delegation: (not set)
Close authority: (not set)
```

Comment: I solved it by using the web3js api. It looks to me the close account CLI is broken. I also noticed the program authority CLI commands for the new v2 deployer are not working. I will reach out to the solana CLI devs.

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
spl-token close --address 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5
```

Comment: Yes, it gives this:
```$ spl-token close --address 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5
Error: Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey=2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5```

Answer (score 0):

Non-native Accounts must have a balance of zero to be closed.
Firstly check your acounts:

spl-token accounts -v

Then try this:

spl-token close <TOKEN_ADDRESS> --recipient <REFUND_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>

<TOKEN_ADDRESS> is the token mint address that you want to close. In the example above, it should be 2WehTH4Hjb1kLU4BYG8Y71KLCwPX95H6xoQen6ngRWk5

<REFUND_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> is another different token account address(not mint address). When closing an Account, all remaining SOL will be transferred to another Solana account.